# Galaxy note 2 emulator work well but not the device

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, samsung-mobile

I made a game for the first time and had just finish the dev. So I sent my game to some friends for beta testing, The apk work well for every tester exept for one using a Samsung Galaxy note 2.

The game crash when he pressed the "play" button. But when I made an emulator with the same carac, the game work well (exept for a switch between 2 activities, but without crashing).

I can't get the note 2 cause my friend is far, so I can't use the LogCat to see whats happened.

My emulator is :

```
Galaxy note 2
720x1280 large xhdpi
Keyboard = off 
skin = on
android 4.1.2 (the same he have)
Proc: MIPS(mips)
Ram 748
vm heap 32 
Storage 1Gb
```

I really don't understand what happend and that make me mad >,<

Answer (score 1):

You can ask your friend to send you the LogCat. 
There maybe some issue specific to his device(conflicts from other apps, etc). Get someone else with a Note 2 to test as well to confirm.
Or I can help you with beta-testing if you want. I'll send the LogCat.